# Nginx downloads file, not displaying the content

Tags: 14.04, php, nginx

On my website, i have some validation file that i need to put in the document root that has no extension just "validation-file",

But when i try to open it from the browser, it downloads instead of opening, all other files with extensions like (.txt) can be opened normally,

My nginx (1.12) config:

```
server {
listen 80;
listen 443 ssl;

root /var/www/website;
error_log /var/log/nginx/website-error.log;
access_log /var/log/nginx/website-access.log;

index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

server_name website.com;
ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/website/nginx_bundle.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/website/website.key;

location / {
    index index.php index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404 /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
}

# pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
#
location ~ \.php$ {
    root /var/www/website;

    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/website/$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;

}

# deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
# concurs with nginx's one
#
location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`nginx` determines the content type from the extension. If the file has no extension, it will use the `default_type`.

You can explicitly set the content type of this file by handling it within its own `location` block:

```
location = /validation-file {
    types {}
    default_type text/html;
}
```

Set `default_type` to whatever the file contains, e.g. `text/html` or `text/plain`, etc.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#types) for more.